# Redis AOF from RDB base file

Tags: redis, database-backups

I'm looking for the best way to backup my Redis data.
I read about RDB and AOF. But from what I think, the best way would be to combine it in the following way:
Create RDB periodically, and only save AOF from that point.
That way, when you restart. Redis can restore the RDB file (which is faster than the whole AOF rollback) and then for the last seconds rollback the AOF file.
The AOF file contains every write since the last RDB.

My question is, is this available in Redis? Or are there any downsides about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how Redis works by default.

See the comments about the `aof-use-rdb-preamble` configuration in the default [`redis.conf`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#L1117).